# How to load webpage after video completes

Tags: javascript, video, html

I have an image that takes up the window, is the first frame of a video clip and has an "enter" button for the website. When you click "enter" it plays the video and then needs to load the home page.

I have tried HTML5's video tag and the 'onend' method, but no luck.
I have tried about 5 different open-source video players-none have scriptable 'onEnd' methods.
I have tried setting a "timeout" function equal to the time of the video...no luck.

I normally would do it in Flash, but it has to play on the iPad.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jase

Answer (score 2):

I believe the event you're looking for is [`onended`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#handler-onended), not `onend`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast reply. Unfortunately, I have tried that as well. Here is the code I am using:
[code]
<script type="text/javascript">
var videoPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
videoPlayer.onended = function(){
    window.location= "http://www.mydomain.net";
}
</script>
<video src="../intro6.OGG" autoplay autobuffer />
[/code]

Thanks again for the quick reply. Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: If you're just going to have your script the way you have it written now, your `<script>` element needs to appear below your `<video>` element.  The alternative is changing your code to an appropriate event listener so it executes after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried it with the <script> tag after the <video> tag, but I haven't tried the event listener method. I'll try it next. Thanks again.

Comment: Just tried it with the onload function (with an Alert call to verify that the function is being called) and the alert works, but not the onended. Perhaps it's a problem with Firefox.

Comment: Here is the latest update: I looked up the DOM specification for onended and it appears that it is a boolean property rather than a function. So I tried setting a timeout to repeatedly look for the onended attribute of the video element to register true, no luck. Maybe this is just not possible.